# Nokia S40 Ovi browser web application tips and tricks

Tags: web-applications, series-40, ovistore

What are some tips and tricks when developing web applications using the Series 40 [Ovi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovi_%28Nokia%29) browser platform?

Comment: can anyone mark this question as community wiki?

Comment: Or vote to close (as it's not a programming 'question')

Comment: It's not, but it's related to programming.

Comment: @silent - what is the question? Community wiki is a destination, not a starting point.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that we have a nice [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). To quote: "What kind of questions should I not ask here? You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." "Tips and tricks about X" is not an answerable question.

Comment: ah, I see. I though this kind of question is accepted too just like on wordpress.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every code that is run on `function()`, the Ovi browser will forward it to server to interpret it. So, make sure you do a minimal function() call. If you have to do it, try to use `mwl.timer()` to add a nice loading effect.

For example:

In `index.html`:

```
<div onclick="loadNews()">load news</div>
```

In `code.js`:

```
function loadNews()
{
    mwl.addClass('#navigation', 'hide');
    mwl.addClass('#container', 'hide');
    mwl.removeClass('#loader', 'hide');
    //Ajax call here.
}
```

You can optimize it to:

In `index.html`:

```
<div onclick="mwl.addClass('#navigation', 'hide');mwl.addClass('#container', 'hide');mwl.removeClass('#loader', 'hide');mwl.timer('loadNewsTimer', 10, 1, 'loadNews()')">load news</div>
```

In `code.js`:

```
function loadNews()
{
    //Ajax call here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding inline JavaScript code, you should wrap your code in `"` (double-quote). It runs on the emulator, but will fail on the device.

For example:

```
<div id='runner' onclick="mwl.addClass('#header', 'hide');mwl.removeClass('#container', 'hide');">command</a>
```